# How to prevent usage of Cloud Run Services while allowing GCFv2 (which requires Cloud Run under the hood)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We are evaluating if it is possible to prevent/block on organisational (or folder) level usage of Cloud Run Services (standalone), while not blocking usage of Cloud Functions v2 (or even v1). GCFv2 requires Artifact Registry which is part of Cloud Run Services.
In other words: We would like to allow GCFv1/v2 deployment, but not general Cloud Run Services deployment.

- Disabling Cloud Run Services API will block usage of GCF v2
- Monitoring based on Asset Inventory is not preventing this in a first place and is a reactive measure - not acceptable.

Comment: Did you try not to grant the cloud run admin role to the users? It should be enough. And why do you want to limit the Cloud Run usage? It's the same thing as Cloud Functions (Cloud Functions v2 is simply a wrapper of Cloud Run). it makes no sense!

Comment: With overlapping permissions between GCFv2 roles I do not want to depend just on IAM for limiting API/Service. (GCF admin/developer as far as I understand would be enough to deploy CR Service as well)
Regarding difference between GCFv2 and CR Services- Google Managed 'wrapper' which is provided by GCFv2 is what makes this approach ok with our requirements. At the same time we'd still want to prevent CR Services from being deployed. Detail reasoning for that I will need to leave out unfortunately.